# TypeError: this.state.requests.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Getting the below error :

```
 this.state.requests.map((request) => {
         return( <div className="member-wrapper" key={request._id}>
    )}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some more information with the question? Because right now it seems that requests is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post more info about how your state is set?

It may be that you are trying to map over an undefined state object. Something like:

```
initialState = {
  requests: []
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = initialState;
  render() {
    // do your this.state.requests.map here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this error because your `requests` property within your `MyRequests` react component's state **isn't an array** to be iterated on. The `.map()` function can only be used for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). I suspect this property hasn't been instantiated properly or is currently a JavaScript object instead.

Hopefully that helps!